# not able to set value using super().x

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: Code Output]

I'm not able to set value to class variable in parent class but able to print it.It is saying attribute doesn't exist even when i am able to print it.

CODE:

```
class Base(object): 
    x=20

class Derived(Base):

    def __init__(self):
        print(super().x)
        super().x=80

obj=Derived()
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here? `Base.x` is a class attribute, if you want to override that as a class attribute in Derived set it the same way. If you want to set an instance attribute, set it on self.

Comment: i am just poking around in python and i really need to know why i am getting value of x using super().x but not able to set any value to x using same,

Answer (score 1):

A `Derived` is a `Base`, i.e. all instances of `Derived` can be treated exactly like instances of `Base`. In your case, that means you simply set `self.x = 80`.